# Is it possible to always automatically pass a command line argument to an install4j installer?

Tags: install4j

Let's say install4j produces the installer file myapp.exe. Is it possible to configure it in such a way that when a double clicks this executable, it will run as `./myapp.exe -manual` for example?

So basically, I'm trying to configure [command line options](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/installers/options.html) in such a way that it's transparent to the end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "Installer->Screen & Actions" step, select the installer and configure the "Arguments" property.

However, the "Arguments" property only has an effect for the JVM, and the "-manual" argument is interpreted by the native launcher, so in this particular case you cannot pre-configure it. "-manual" is also a trouble-shooting option and should not be set by default.

Comment: I see, that's good to know. In that case, is it possible to have the installer always prefer the dynamically bundled JRE? The "JRE Search Sequence" section is empty and "Install only if no other suitable JRE is found" is unchecked. And yet, it still finds the JRE of a previous install which can be verified when I use the argument /create-i4j-log. That's why I was hoping to use -manual since it seems to skip the search sequence and prefer the dynamic bundle. I'm using v6 of install4j if that makes a difference.

Comment: Why don't you statically bundle the JRE then? That is a lot less error prone, especially regarding proxies.

Comment: That seems to be the best solution right now. The dynamically packaged JRE is preferable in this case because it's a central location for the JREs used across our projects (used for other purposes). But if it's not possible to force the usage of dynamic JREs, then statically packaged might be the best option then. Thank you for your help!